How can I view the name of an attachment uploaded by a guest user during a flow from a Community?
I have a public community with a screen flow that allows a guest user to upload an attachment.  After the attachment is uploaded, I use the following variable Attachment_Title to store the name of the attachment.  I then include this variable in a text template.
When I run the flow as myself, everything works great, and the file name is stored in Attachment_Title and I can view the filename.  However, when I run the flow as a guest user, the variable Attachment_Title is blank
When I go to my Files tab, I can see the attachment that the guest user uploaded, so I know the guest user has permission to upload the file.
I'm thinking it's a persmission setting, but no idea which one it is.
